# 404 Not Found Nginx Error on Deployment of React App Build

Tags: reactjs, nginx, frontend, web-deployment

We have used “react-oauth2-pkce” library to implement authentication in our react app. The authentication is working just fine in the development setup, however, when we are creating its production build using npm and deploying it in the nginx web server, we are getting the following “404 Not Found” nginx error after the authentication is completed in the third party wso2 authentication provider and when the uri is being redirected to the original react application of the prod build.

PS: Please note that we have hosted the react app on port 3000 as is visible for the prod build on the nginx web server and so it’s not the default react development server which is up on port 3000.(we have intentionally kept it on port 3000 so that we do not have to change the redirect URIs again and again to toggle between the dev and the prod builds.)

[404 Not Found Error's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePN5x.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by making a change in the nginx conf file as follows:

```
location / {
try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

The direct requests to index.html file were working fine but the other requests were not working so to forward the other requests to index.html file, we did the above the change.